# Family chart with Horizontal and vertical line connectors using Vis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, vis.js

I need Family tree similar to [image: FamilyTree] with unidirectional arrows at the node connecting point. I have gone through the examples http://visjs.org/network_examples.html, I am not clear which of those network examples can easily be modified to make my required chart. I tried modifying Hierarchical Method ( directed) example but it is not working, when I add new node and connect it to right end node, the graph is breaking up.  I want this connected lines between nodes in horizontal and vertical fashion as shown in the attached figure also. Can any one help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of 90°-edges are [not possible at the moment](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2038). There is already an [open feature-request](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2053) for this in the vis-library.

The closest thing vis.js can do with version 4.16.1 is the following:

[image]

[Here you'll find the example code](http://jsbin.com/meriti/4/edit?html,output)